# Sort and counting a column without uniq in bash

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, count, sh

I want to add a count of only the first column using bash, without doing uniq, like this:

input:

```
58311s2727  NC_000082.6 100.00  50  
58311s2727  NC_000083.6 100.00  60
58311s2727  NC_000084.6 100.00  70
58310s2691  NC_000080.6 100.00  30
58310s2691  NC_000081.6 100.00  20
58308s2441  NC_000074.6 100.00  50
```

output:

```
3  58311s2727   NC_000082.6 100.00  50  
3  58311s2727   NC_000083.6 100.00  60
3  58311s2727   NC_000084.6 100.00  70
2  58310s2691   NC_000080.6 100.00  30
2  58310s2691   NC_000081.6 100.00  20
1  58308s2441   NC_000074.6 100.00  50
```

I tried:

```
sort input.txt | cut -f1 | uniq -c
```

but the output is not what I want. I want to know if there will be simple ways to solve this.

Comment: Can you please post any solution that you've tried?

Comment: i tried: sort input.txt|cut -f1|uniq -c ,
but the output is not what i want, want to know if there will be simple ways to solve this

Comment: if you want to use uniq you can do: `awk '{print $1}' | uniq -c`

if you really don't want to use uniq you can do: `awk '{count[$1]++}END{for(j in count) print j, count[j]}'`

Comment: awk '{count[$1]++}END{for(j in count) print j, count[j]}' will do similar as |uniq -c, which will cut away all other columns, and removing all the repeats, thats not what i want

Comment: The question looks good. No reason for downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this in awk.  But as Aaron said, it will require reading the input twice, since the first time you hit a particular line, you don't know how many other times  you'll hit it.

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next} {print a[$1],$0}' inputfile inputfile
```

This goes through the file the first time, populating an array with a counter of the first field.  Then it goes through a second time, printing the count along with each line.

You can adjust the `print` statement to suite your formatting requirements (perhaps replacing it with `printf`).

---

If you don't want to use awk, and really want this to work natively in bash, you could use a couple of one-liners with for loops to achieve nearly the same results:

```
$ declare -A a
$ while read word therest; do ((a[$word]++)); done < inputfile
$ while read word therest; do printf "%5d\t%s\t%s\n" "${a[$word]}" "$word" "$therest"; done < inputfile
```

The `declare -A` is required because `$a` needs to be an associative array, with the first word of each line as the key.  `awk`, on the other hand, treats every array as associative.  Note that this solution does not maintain your whitespace.

Comment: thank you!! this is exact what i want!
 awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next} {printf ("%5s\t%s\n", a[$1], $0)}' input.txt input.txt >output.txt

Comment: @once: Note that this cannot be used with data that is not in a file (for example, in a pipeline) because it must be able to read the same data twice.  It also stores all the keys in memory, which probably isn't going to be a major problem, but it is worth being aware of that.  Of course, reading a file twice is more expensive than reading it once, and reading it once is all that is really necessary.  In its favour, this technique works correctly even if the data is not sorted on input.  Of course, the output isn't sorted either in that case.

Answer (score 1):

With sorted input, you can simply use `awk`, capturing the set of lines that have the same key and printing the previous set out when the key changes.  Handling EOF is a tad messy; you have to repeat the printing.  You could write an `awk` function to do the printing, but it is almost overkill for something this simple.

#### `script.awk`

```
$1 != old_key { if (n_keys > 0) for (i = 0; i < n_keys; i++) print n_keys, saved[i]; n_keys = 0 }
{ saved[n_keys++] = $0; old_key = $1 }
END { if (n_keys > 0) for (i = 0; i < n_keys; i++) print n_keys, saved[i] }
```

#### Example runs

For the sample input `input.txt` (which is already grouped), the output is:

```
$ awk -f script.awk input.txt
3 58311s2727  NC_000082.6 100.00  50  
3 58311s2727  NC_000083.6 100.00  60
3 58311s2727  NC_000084.6 100.00  70
2 58310s2691  NC_000080.6 100.00  30
2 58310s2691  NC_000081.6 100.00  20
1 58308s2441  NC_000074.6 100.00  50
$
```

If you want it sorted, sort it first:

```
$ sort input.txt | awk -f script.awk
1 58308s2441  NC_000074.6 100.00  50
2 58310s2691  NC_000080.6 100.00  30
2 58310s2691  NC_000081.6 100.00  20
3 58311s2727  NC_000082.6 100.00  50  
3 58311s2727  NC_000083.6 100.00  60
3 58311s2727  NC_000084.6 100.00  70
$
```

Note that amongst other advantages, this can process data from a pipeline because it doesn't need to process the file twice, unlike at least one of the other solutions, which is currently accepted.  It also only keeps as many lines in memory as there are lines in the biggest group of a common key, so even fairly big files are unlikely to stress the memory on the system.  (The `sort` probably imposes more memory load than the `awk` does.)

#### `script2.awk`

Using a function, and some white space, the code becomes:

```
function dump_keys(    i) {
    if (n_keys > 0)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < n_keys; i++)
            print n_keys, saved[i]
    }
    n_keys = 0
}
$1 != old_key { dump_keys() }
              { saved[n_keys++] = $0; old_key = $1 }
END           { dump_keys() }
```

The variable `i` is local to the function (a quirk of `awk`).  I could simply omit it from the argument list since `i` is not used elsewhere in the script.

This produces the same output as `script.awk`.

Answer (score 0):

Without `uniq`, you'll have to read the input twice. There are ways to do that in pure BASH, but this is when I'd switch to a proper scripting language like Python 2:

```
import codecs
from collections import Counter

filename='...'
encoding='...' # file encoding

counter = Counter()
with codecs.open(filename, 'r', encoding) as fh:
   for line in fh:
       parts = line.split(' ')
       counter[parts[0]] += 1

with codecs.open(filename, 'r', encoding) as fh:
   for line in fh:
       parts = line.split(' ')
       count = counter[parts[0]]
       print '%d%s' % (count, line),
```

Comment: i use python too, but my input is large, want to know if there is simpler way using bash

Comment: @once: define large.  As in megabytes, gigabytes, terabytes, or larger?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler in megabytes, but i've got a few of them

Comment: OK; and the 'few of them' is tens, hundreds, thousands, millions of such files? Megabytes of data is not big these days.

Comment: yes.. my data reach giga, but i dont hv a good computer, so have to seperate into smaller files, and seems that bash works fastest in my case

Comment: Define "simpler". The Python script will use less memory and run faster.